# retaining margins with min-width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a header containing a title and menu. The header has a margin, and a minimum width equal to the width of the menu. When the user resizes the window, the margin on the right-hand side disappears when the minimum width is reached. What I want is for the margin to be included in the minimum size of the header. Does anyone have any ideas?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id="header">
                <ul id="title">
                    <li>
                        Title
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Profile</li>
                    <li>Projects</li>
                    <li>News</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li class="stretch"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #header {
        background-color: orange;
        margin: 1em;
    }

    #title {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #title li {
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu {
        width: 40em;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    #menu li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #menu .stretch {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
        //SET MINIMUM WINDOW WIDTH TO MENU WIDTH
        var menu = $('#menu'),
            header = $('#header');

            header.css('min-width', menu.width());

        $(window).resize(function() {
        });
    });
```

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3u7nLgz/

Comment: Have you tried setting a min-width on the header?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your .menu class to:

```
#menu {
    /*width: 40em;*/
    margin-right: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I don't think you want to specify a width here, and adding a margin to your block level ul element will satisfy your need for a margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/L3u7nLgz/1/

**Edit:**  You can just use padding then on your .header.

```
#header {
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3u7nLgz/2/

Comment: The width has to stay because I don't want the menu to span the full length of the parent.

Is there a way to retain the margin on the header itself? While this solution works aesthetically I'm concerned it will cause some confusion to work with later when I start positioning things to the top right of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by adding transparent borders to the header element. Not exactly a fix to the above problem but the closest and most consistent solution I could find to my problem.